# Flutter animation interpolation

Tags: animation, flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to rotate a widget (which is not part of the problem as it handles the rotation itself  via constructor parameter) based on an animation which interpolates between the previous rotation position a new one obtained with a plugin function. The value of that function (`FlutterCompass.events.listen`) updates asynchroniously on a regular basis, and it rebuilds the Tween objetc everytime in order to represent the update of the position of the widget. Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/animation.dart';
import 'package:flutter_compass/flutter_compass.dart';
import 'package:compass_test/compass.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  double _direction;
  double _angle = 0.0;
  Animation<double> _animation;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Tween<double> _tween;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
      _animationController =
          AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400), vsync: this);
      _tween = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.0);
      _animation = _tween.animate(_animationController)
          ..addListener(() {
              setState(() {
                _angle =_animationController.value;
              });
          });
    _direction = 0;

    FlutterCompass.events.listen((double direction) {
      print(_animationController.status);
      if(_direction !=direction){
        _tween = Tween<double>(
          begin: _direction,
          end: direction);
        _animationController.reset();
        _tween.animate(_animationController);
        _animationController.forward();
      }
      _direction = direction;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
                child: Compass(height: 300, width: 300, angleToNorth: _angle)
              )
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

However, as I've been able to see with some debug, the values returned from `_animationController.value` only vary from 0.0 to 1.0, which is not what I tought was supposed to happen: I expected them to vary from the previous value of `_direction` to the new `direction` value. How can I achive that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is how animation controllers are suppose to work. With some extra lines you can even add a curve to the change in values from 0.0 to 1.0. But the values will always go from 0.0 to 1.0. So what you can do is update _angles value like this `_angle = degree of angle * _animationController.value`. So lets say your angle is 50 degree. So when you start your animation the animation controller's value will start from 0.0 which will be multiplied by 50 giving you 0. And as the animation controllers value moves from 0.0 to 1.0 the _angle's value will also change and in the end giving you 50 as 1.0 * 50 is 50! But as you mentioned you just want to rotate your widget. So instead of this you can use a tween animation builder of type double and update the end value if you want to run the animation again; the animation will continue from the previous value.